# How can i enable Multi selection on a tree viewer after creating it?

Tags: java

Actually I just created a table viewer for my application and a requirement comes to me in such a way that the multi selection should be enabled after creating the viewer. Please help me to do this.

Comment: The obvious questions: What did you try? Which UI framework are you talking about? How should multi selection work in general, i.e. what should be selectable etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi Selection can be set at the time of tree construction or tree-viewer construction only. the style is a member variable of Widget class which accessibility is default so we cannot access the same and there is no method already available to set the style object.so it seems not possible to change selection after Treeviewer or tree creation.